# How to Avoid or Diagnose Error 500 in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, error-handling

When working with Laravel 5, I often run into HTTP 500 Internal Server Errors. For example, I may have overlooked a missing `;` in a controller method.

In my `.env`, I have:

```
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

Is there a way to get error messages to display in the browser instead of an HTTP error?

If not, can you provide a complete list of logs to check to diagnose these errors? For example, a forgotten `;` in a controller method produces neither an entry in `storage/logs/laravel.log` nor in my `nginx` log file nor in my `php-fpm` log file. (I use `nginx` and `php-fpm` rather than Apache).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using whoops to handle 500 errors https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/whoops-20-laravel-52